# Add SQL data to URL with PHP

Tags: php, sql, url

I have some basic code which selects data from a database and echo's it into a HTML table and also add's a link to the echo'd out data. This all works fine. What I want to do is add another piece of data from my database (product_id) to the URL. Here is the code:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db_test");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_products");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Products:</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><a href='product.php?id='>" . $row['product_name'] . "</a></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I want to add product_id from my database at the end of

```
<a href='product.php?id='
```

so the product_id becomes the ID of the page. How would I do this? I have experimented but it has resulted in numerous errors. I am sure this is a simple syntax thing but it' s bugging me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing the tag A before placing your data into href.

I think it should work:

```
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Products:</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><a href=\"product.php?id=". $row['product_id'] ."\">" . $row['product_name'] . "</a></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

Answer back if it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you mean product_id instead of one of the product_name's? That works. Cheers.

Comment: Sure, I copied the whole string and didn't change the array position.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you should put the '> after " . $row['product_name'] . " so that the line would read:

```
 echo "<td><a href='product.php?id=" . $row['product_name'] . "'>" . $row['product_name'] . "</a></td>";
```

Comment: Everything I have is working fine. What I want to do is add another thing to it.